# Menu with action bar sherlock

Tags: android, menu, actionbarsherlock

I need an example or a tutorial
on how to add menu items with action bar sherlock

When I use the simple menu 
with the imports

```
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

when I call

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.settings_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.goToSettings:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SetPreference.class));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

then I get the Cannot override the final method from SherlockActivity error.

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+O to fix all your imports. Make sure you are using the "android support jar" that comes with ActionBarSherlock and make sure that the ActionBarSherlock is added on a project library to your project.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You have to use `Menu`, `MenuInflater` and `MenuItem` classes from `com.actionbarsherlock.view` package:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.settings_menu, menu);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

BTW, `ActionBarSherlock` contains a lot of samples.

Comment: Just like to comment that if you find your home button click doesn't work when using ActionBarSherlock, @StenaviN's answer will solve your problem. Sure wish I saw this 3 hrs ago...

Comment: There is only an error in code, the return statement must be:
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

Comment: @Guido However, the implementation of `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` is just `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { return true; }`, at least if the super is SherlockFragmentActivity.

Comment: @Guido, I have corrected _return_ statement as suggested. However here is a quote from developer documentation: _You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you return false it will not be shown._

Answer (score 3):

I used @StenaviN 's answer above but ran into problems with onContextItemSelected. [This post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/actionbarsherlock/OBhjAV_3nHw/YfhPBjeBd-gJ) solved it for me.

Basically, you just have to use

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    /* ... */
}
```

instead of

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I used @Matt's answer above but ran into problems with onContextItemSelected.

Basically, you just have to use

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {
    /* ... */
}
```

instead of

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {
    /* ... */
}
```