# android : action bar with option menu in one activity

Tags: android, android-layout, drop-down-menu, submenu, optionmenu

How can i create this type of Action bar and also option menu in one activity.
i am usin  action bar sherlock libs. how can show at same time

[image]

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931811/menu-with-action-bar-sherlock

Comment: i want both menu and action in one activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add actions to your menu.xml specifying **android:showAsAction="never"** and they will be shown in option menu

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/viewContact"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/view_contact" />
```